# How can I position three divs in a page?

Tags: html, position

I want the page to be split vertically, with one div on the right half of the page and the other two divs on the left half. How could I do this? My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
div2v{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
div4{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div4">
<iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="width: 100%; height: 400px" name="internal"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="div4">
<iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="width: 100%; height: 400px" name="internal"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="div2v">
<iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="width: 100%; height: 800px" name="internal"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there a better way of arranging iframes on a page (without Javascript)?

Comment: Don’t use the same `id`more than once (`id="div4"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your code to following

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#div2v{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#div4{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div4">
<iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="width: 100%; height: 400px" name="internal"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="width: 100%; height: 400px" name="internal"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="div2v">
<iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="width: 100%; height: 400px" name="internal"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Changes made

1. Update css selector -> `div2v to #div2v` and `div4` to `#div4`
2. Update html from

   ```
   <div id="div4">
     <iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="width: 100%; height: 400px" name="internal"></iframe>
   </div>
   <div id="div4">
      <iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="width: 100%; height: 400px" name="internal"></iframe>
   </div>
   ```

to

```
<div id="div4">
    <iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="width: 100%; height: 400px" name="internal"></iframe>

    <iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="width: 100%; height: 400px" name="internal"></iframe>
</div>
```

For reference - http://jsfiddle.net/1aywhc2s/

Comment: Hi @nikhil. Thank you very much for your suggestion. I spotted a small error in one of my iframes also (the height should be 800px for the iframe of the right div).

Comment: @d3pd - Good we worked out solution in collaboration :)

Answer (score 3):

Modified your code :-) No need to set height in px I have made it responsive, you can review this solution

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#div2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#div1{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#div3{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="width: 100%; height:  100%" name="internal"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" name="internal"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div3">
  <iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" name="internal"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Vishal. Thank you very much for your suggestion. It is structured nicely.